# Importing large csv file into Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, import

I'm writing a script which imports a large csv file in Excel document.
I try to use a faster way to enter the data and pass the array directly to Excel without looping it.

```
$p = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Report.csv" -Delimiter "`t"
$Excel01 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Excel01.Visible = $True 
$Workbook01 = $Excel01.Workbooks.Add() 
$Worksheet01 = $Workbook01.Sheets.Item(1) 
$Worksheet01.Activate() 

$Worksheet01.Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.Value() = $p | select field1,field2...
```

But when I run this it hungs...How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with opening the CSV file directly in Excel?

Comment: Or using the Import from Text-wizard.

Comment: David Brabant, I need query SQL server for data and save it as xlsx file and send it by email (and repeat this stuff several times), that's why I try to automate these actions. So, I use bcp command line tool to export data from mssql to csv file and then I need somehow convert it in the Excel format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OpenText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097%28v=office.15%29.aspx) already exists in Excel. Note, however, that you MUST change the extension of the text file to something other than `.csv`, because Excel has its own mind about how files with that particular extension should be handled.

```psh
New-Variable -Option Constant -Name xlDelimited -Value 1
New-Variable -Option Constant -Name xlTextQualifierNone -Value -4142
New-Variable -Option Constant -Name xlWorkbookDefault -Value 51

$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
$txt = $csv -replace '\.csv$','.txt'
$xls = $csv -replace '\.csv$','.xlsx'

Rename-Item $csv $txt

$xl = New-Object -COM 'Excel.Application'
$xl.Workbooks.OpenText($txt, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $xlDelimited, $xlTextQualifierNone, $false, $true)
$wb = $xl.Workbooks | ? { $_.FullName -eq $txt }

$wb.SaveAs($xls, $xlWorkbookDefault)
$wb.Close()

$xl.Quit()
```

The `[Type]::Missing` values are required for parameters that should retain their default value.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. Maybe you can optimize it :-)

```
$p = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Report.csv" -Delimiter "`t"
$Excel01 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Excel01.Visible = $True 
$Workbook01 = $Excel01.Workbooks.Add() 
$Worksheet01 = $Workbook01.Sheets.Item(1) 
$Worksheet01.Activate() 

#Add csv header to excel
For ($i = 0; $i -lt ($p | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}).Count; $i ++) {
    $Worksheet01.Cells.Item(1,(1+$i)) = "$(($p | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"})[$i].Name)"
}

#Add csv data to ecxel
$startRow = 2
For ($i = 0; $i -lt ($p | Measure-Object).Count; $i ++) {
    For ($i2 = 0; $i2 -lt ($p[$i] | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}).Count; $i2 ++) {
        $PropertyName = ($p[$i2] | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"})[$i2].Name
        $Worksheet01.Cells.Item($startRow,(1+$i2)) = "$($p[$i].$PropertyName)"
    }
    $startRow ++
}
```